# Ошибка при создании поля типа FloatField в форме Django

Tags: django, база-данных, float, интернет-магазин, html-form

*Я новобранец. Так что, если вопрос тупой, вы были предупреждены.*

***Вопрос такой:* как правильно сделать форму, которая будет содержать поле для ввода цены (число с двумя знаками после запятой)?**

Мой проект - интернет-магазин.

Сейчас делаю страницу для добавления новых записей о товарах в БД.
Под словом "запись" подразумеваю сущность с такой информацией (4 поля):

1. ID (primary_key);
2. "title";
3. "description";
4. "price" (типа django.db.models.FloatField).

В html-коде страницы создал форму:

```
<form method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.title }}
    <br>
    {{ form.description }}
    <br>
    {{ form.price }}
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить в базу данных</button>

</form>
```

Подготовил файл forms.py:

```
from .models import Product
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea, FloatField


class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["title", "description", "price"]
        widgets = {
            "title": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Как называется?'
            }),
            "description": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Добавьте описание.'
            }),
            "price": FloatField()
        }
```

Но возникает ошибка со строчкой:
`"price": FloatField()`

Вот что уже попробовал:

- Сначала вообще думал, что могу для FloatField использовать атрибут attrs, как использовал его для TextInput и Textarea. Но поробовал разобраться в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField), понял, что вообще не то делаю;
- Если оставляю эту строку так `"price": FloatField()` (с пустыми скобками у класса FloatField), Django выдаёт ошибку: 'FloatField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute';
- Если убираю, поле для ввода цены ("price") начинает с какого-то чёрта отображаться. Но отображается без применения стилей, естественно.

Будет полезно, если объясние детали, поделитесь полезными ресурсами или просто укажете конкретную строку документации (или, если вопрос некорректный, подскажете, почему так).

Comment: Используйте IntegerField. Вместо рублей храните копейки в базе.

Comment: Для денег обычно используют decimal